# C++ - Is it bad practice to use compiler specific functions?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, compiler

My requirement is simple, I want to be able to count the number of bits in a number. With a little bit of research, I found that `MSVC` has [`__popcnt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/popcnt16-popcnt-popcnt64?view=msvc-160), `GCC` has [`__builtin_popcount`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)  and so on.

At this stage, it's one function. Later on here are some that would also be very useful in my program, but are again compiler-specific

- `_byteswap_uint64`
- `__shiftright128`, `__shiftleft128`

But then I would have to do

```cpp
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
...
#elif defined(__GNUG__)
...
...
#endif
```

to make it work on other compilers. But this makes the program look very ugly and very hard to maintain.

**The question**: Is it bad to use compiler-specific functions in your source? i.e Should I avoid using them?

Comment: No programming technique is good or bad **without any context**. You need to know what your program's intended life cycle is, then you can evaluate how many and which compilers you want to support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it bad to use compiler-specific functions in your source? i.e Should I avoid using them?

The answer is "it depends." A naive hand-rolled `popcount` function requires but a few lines of code that are easy to understand, easy to test, and highly portable.

Suppose on performance testing you find that the CPU spends a tiny, tiny fraction of the execution time in this nice simple chunk of code. In this case, there is no reason to pollute your code with `#ifdef this`, `#elif defined that`, and `#elif defined something_else`. Optimized code oftentimes is rather ugly code, with `#ifdef` being about as ugly as it gets.

On the other hand, suppose on performance testing you find that the CPU spends a significant fraction of the execution time in this nice simple chunk of code, and suppose you find that the compiler-specific intrinsics reduce this by a significant amount. This can justify getting ugly, but keep in mind that that ugly code may be fragile. Your code is now at the mercy of vendors maintaining backward compatibility with their intrinsics. There is no guarantee that that will continue.

One final note: In the future you might well find that your naive hand-rolled `popcount` function suddenly becomes just as fast as the compiler-specific ugliness. Compiler writers (and hence compilers) have become ever more adept at recognizing the intent of code. A compiler might well recognize that your small number of lines of code does exactly what `__popcount_using_specialized_assembly_instructions` does, and thereby compiles your code to call that specialized function. You could have done the same using a bunch of macro commands. But what happens when the authors of the library change the name of the function? The compiler will be cognizant of that change and compile your naive hand-rolled `popcount` function to call the renamed function. Your macro plagued code will not.

Comment: "In the future you might well...". This already happens today: Implementing a bit rotate using bit shifting results in an internal rotate call on all relevant compilers. The thing only is: Using the built-in extension directly guarantees you that it is used instead of having to hope for the best and that the compiler will understand your code. If I tell you you can get $1000 right now, guaranteed or you can fill out a form and maybe that will get you $1000, which option would you take?

Comment: @Mecki It's more like *You can track down and fill out a simple but little known form right now, and get $1000 right now, guaranteed, as long as you don't move over the border, or you may potentially get the $1000 without condition, though also without guarantee.*

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using such compiler-specific functions in the main body of your code, exactly because of the `#ifdef` hell it creates.

If such a compiler-specific function is the best choice at some point in your code, you should wrap it in an (inline) function of your own. That way, you can

- keep all the `#ifdef` logic in one place, or
- provide multiple implementations in different files, where the build system ensures the correct file for the current compiler is chosen

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, that's what I tried to do, which is to keep all the `#ifdef` in one place. But again I think I could only cover three of the major compilers (`gcc, msvc, clang`) . Would that still be bad?

Comment: @AryanParekh, whether that is bad or not depends on the set of compilers you need/want to support. You could always provide a (less efficient) general implementation that gets used by other compilers.

Comment: One of the best places to keep all the `#ifdef` logic in one place is a library designed for portability. In C++, some examples are Boost and Qt.

Comment: @mouviciel I haven't seen a very good library for fast and easy bit-manipulation. However C++20 introduces the `bit` header with a lot of them

Comment: @AryanParekh You would have an implementation like #ifdef gcc ... #elif defined(msvc) ... #elif defined(clang) ... #else <plain C implementation> #endif so you cover all cases. If you add a new compiler, your code works but is slow for that compiler, but then you can add a special case at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function in terms of the corresponding builtin, For example:

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define POPCOUNT(x) __popcnt(x)
#elif defined(**GNUG**)
#define POPCOUNT(x) __builtin_popcount(x)
#endif

Then in your code use POPCOUNT() and the correct builtin is used.

Comment: Add an #else branch with an implementation in pure C, so it works everywhere.

Comment: The key insight is to use the available facilities in C++ (e.g. macros, if necessary) to create a **programming abstraction layer** so that the users of these functions (i.e. algorithm writers who need to count the bits in the fastest possible, and possibly hardware-specific ways) can rest assured that a function (abstraction) will take care of that, and not having to see the ugliness. [OpenCV has an hardware abstraction layer (HAL) library](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d6/d19/namespacecv_1_1hal.html) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a C++ related question, as this question applies to all languages and compiler (e.g. also C) or runtime (e.g. different JavaScript implementation in browsers).

And to me the answer always has been:

- If your code only has to support one specific compiler/runtime, of course you should use compiler specific language extensions. E.g. when I add C code to an Objective-C project for macOS, this project will never be built with anything but Xcode and Xcode will very likely never switch to another C compiler than clang, so using clang specific extensions is certainly okay.
- Otherwise it is still okay as long as you offer a compiler/runtime neutral alternative as a fallback, since what would you lose that way? For compilers you support directly, you've made the best choice and for all other compilers, you made the same choice that you had made for all compilers otherwise and you can still add support for more compilers later on.